# Retrieve accepted offers from last week in Taleo

Tags: xml, taleo, taleo-connect-client

I have a Taleo Client Connect export which retrieves offers from Taleo Recruiting 17.4. I want to filter my results to only include offers that were accepted within the past seven days.

My filter works if I manually specify a date in the XML data, but I can't figure out how to calculate last week's date at runtime.

```
<quer:filtering xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
  <quer:greaterThan>
    <quer:field path="AcceptedDate"/>
    <quer:date>2019-02-22</quer:date> <!--Should equal [CURRENT_DATE]-[7_DAYS]-->
  </quer:greaterThan>
</quer:filtering>
```

**How can I export offers that were accepted within the past week using Taleo Connect Client?**

---

*Full export*:

```
<quer:query productCode="RC1704" model="http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01" projectedClass="Offer" locale="en" mode="CSV" csvheader="true" largegraph="true" preventDuplicates="false" xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
  <quer:subQueries/>
  <quer:projections>
    <quer:projection>
      <quer:field path="AcceptedDate"/>
    </quer:projection>
    <quer:projection>
      <quer:field path="Application,Candidate,Number"/>
    </quer:projection>
    <quer:projection>
      <quer:field path="Application,Requisition,ContestNumber"/>
    </quer:projection>
  </quer:projections>
  <quer:projectionFilterings/>
  <quer:filterings>
    <quer:filtering>
      <quer:greaterThan>
        <quer:field path="AcceptedDate"/>
        <quer:date>2019-02-22</quer:date> <!--Should equal [CURRENT_DATE]-[7_DAYS]-->
      </quer:greaterThan>
    </quer:filtering>
  </quer:filterings>
  <quer:sortings/>
  <quer:sortingFilterings/>
  <quer:groupings/>
  <quer:joinings/>
</quer:query>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this complex filter:

```
<quer:filtering xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
    <quer:greaterThan>
        <quer:field path="AcceptedDate"/>
        <quer:castAsDate>
            <quer:addDays>
                <quer:date type="now"/>
                <quer:integer>-7</quer:integer>
            </quer:addDays>
        </quer:castAsDate>
    </quer:greaterThan>
</quer:filtering>
```

Comment: Is there documentation for the different available date types?

Comment: I don't think that there is documentation for this. However you can take a look at the schema to see the available options and the schema also contains some extra information. The schema for export queries is named "TaleoConnectQuery.xsd" and it is located in the following folder: C:\Taleo Connect Client\docs\xsd